# SSRS Custom Colour does not want to work

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts

I have custom colors that I am applying to my SSRS Doughnut Chart.

Only thing is its not applying the colors specified. As far as I can see it just uses default.

Am I missing a setting or something?

I am applying it at Series Properties > Fill > (Style = Solid) > Color Expression as Follow:

```
=Switch(Fields!WCode.Value = 102, "Aqua",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 103, "Red",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 104, "Yellow",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 105, "LightGrey",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 106, "Purple",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 107, "HotPink",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 108, "Maroon",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 109, "Khaki",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 110, "DarkOliveGreen",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 111, "Plum",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 113, "Pink",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 117, "Lime",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 118, "Orange",
         "White")
```

I have cleaned the solution also deleted the project data file in the project folder.

I am at a loss and your assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=Switch(Fields!WCode.Value = 102, "Aqua",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 103, "Red",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 104, "Yellow",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 105, "LightGrey",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 106, "Purple",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 107, "HotPink",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 108, "Maroon",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 109, "Khaki",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 110, "DarkOliveGreen",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 111, "Plum",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 113, "Pink",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 117, "Lime",
        Fields!WCode.Value = 118, "Orange",
        true,"White")
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: You are my Hero! What is the significance of the True?

Comment: @MardusDavel, you are welcome. If my answer solved your issue you can [mark it as the correct answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to close the question positively.

Comment: @MardusDavel It's not like an `IF...THEN...ELSE`, there is no `ELSE` in `switch()`